Cannot resizable table on tinymce-vue
I first time use tinymce editor on vue. I add all plugins and make toolbar. everything work successfully but after creating table i cannot change resize columns. how to do this? I try many times. It is my code:
<template>
  <editor v-model="editorValue" :init="init"></editor>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, ref, watch, toRefs } from 'vue'
import { createFile } from '@/views/Files/filesApi'
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce.js'
import plugins from './plugins.js'
// import 'tinymce/models/dom'



import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  plugins: {
    type: [String, Array],
    default: 'quickbars emoticons table image link styles',
  },
  toolbar: {
    type: [String, Array],
    default: `
       undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft
        aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote link | image   |  table | emoticons`,
  },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
const buttonPlugins =
  'emoticons preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media code codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount textpattern autosave '

const toolbar =
  ' fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor bold italic underline strikethrough link table image | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify outdent indent |   bullist numlist | blockquote subscript superscript  |     indent2em lineheight formatpainter '

const init = reactive({
  height: 250,

  menubar: true,
  
 
  plugins: buttonPlugins,
  fontsize_formats: '12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 22px 24px 28px 32px 36px 48px 56px 72px',
  lineheight_formats: '0.5 0.8 1 1.2 1.5 1.75 2 2.5 3 4 5',
  toolbar: toolbar,
  table_resize_bars: true,
  table_appearance_options: true,
  resize: true,
  elementpath: false,
  branding: false,
  image_caption: true,
})

const { modelValue } = toRefs(props)
const editorValue = ref(modelValue.value)

watch(modelValue, (newValue) => {
  editorValue.value = newValue
})

watch(editorValue, (newValue) => {
  emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
})
</script>

